# Chrome Extension Icon Manifest

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

How to change Chrome Extension icon in this page?

[image: extension description]

Here's my manifest code :

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Demo",
  "description": "This is demo.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon128.png",
    "icons": {
       "16": "icon16.png",
       "48": "icon48.png",
      "128": "icon128.png"
    },
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ]
}
```

The icon on toolbar is changed, but not on the `chrome://extension` page.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Set `"icons"`  key in `manifest.json`.

The `browser_action.icons` key is what gets displayed in the toolbar (and will probably only use 16, 24, and 32 sized images, see [browserAction](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction)).

The one displayed in `chrome://extensions` is a top level `icons` key.  In the [manifest documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest), look for the 6th entry, so that your manifest has an top-level entry, like:

```json
{
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

It should be:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Demo",
  "description": "This is demo.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "storage"]
}
```

See: [Chrome Extension Manifest Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest)