# How to add icon to chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've attempted [this guide from Google](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/icons), [this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939974/how-i-can-change-default-icon-in-chrome-extension), and [this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459939/chrome-extension-icon-manifest). I followed what I read but somehow it's not updating the icon when I see it in my extensions. Someone mentioned a dashboard, but my extension a brief script I've saved locally, and update locally when testing. This is my manifest:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Submit Server Glory",
"version": "1.1",
"content_scripts":[
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }
],
"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Submit Server Glory",
    "default_icon": "money128.jpg"
},
"icons": {
  "16": "money16.jpg",
  "48": "money48.jpg",
  "128": "money128.jpg"
},
"permissions": ["tabs"]
}
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459939/chrome-extension-icon-manifest

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. Your manifest already sets the icons correctly, assuming the paths are correct. There is no other method.

Comment: That's my point, I even renamed my files to iconx.jpg and it still isn't updating in chrome. Do I need to restart chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like PNGs work and **JPEGs explicitly DON'T work**, which is a strange constraint for such a popular image.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue aswell, you might be using the new dashboard which doesn't give the option to change the extension icon. I think it may not update since its new and still in progress. If you wanted to set your icon you can `opt out`, edit your extension, selected extension icon, update, then `opt in` again to the new dashboard with your extension icon set. However, it resets whenever you push a new update which is quite annoying

Comment: Where do I opt in or out? Can't find it. I thought this was the only way to set icons

Comment: If you're using the new dashboard there should be a little blue box in the bottom left cornrer saying `feedback` and `show more`, open that up and theres a little link to opt out, you can opt in through a yellow box at the top in the old dashboard

Comment: I'm not using any dashboard, I load my extension unpacked whenever I'm working on it.

Comment: Ahhh ok ok I see the problem now, I'm pretty sure they only accept .png you are using .jpg. I'm sure it says something about that on the docs

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/icons says PNG is the general pick but others are supported, maybe try doing png instead and if that doesn't work it'll be something else like the dimensions or path

Comment: Very late reply, yes that was the problem. It looks like PNGs work and **JPEGs explicitly DON'T work**, which is a strange constraint for such a popular image. Thank you. Could you post that as answer please?